# Factorial in Python using while

Tags: python, factorial

why this function doesn't work as a factorial function?

```
def Factor(n):
    while n>=1:
        print n*(n-1)
    return 1
```

Comment: Because `n` doesn't change? and is still `>=1`?

Comment: And it will return 1 no matter what... that is if it ever returns

Comment: So it does work as a factorial function, but only computes `1!`.

Comment: It doesn't even do that.

Comment: @xnx it should work for 0 though

Comment: Why not just use the built-in factorial function? See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html for using math.factorial(x)

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
def Factor(n):
    val=1
    while n>=1:
        val = val * n
        n = n-1
    return  val
```

Answer (score 1):

You have recursion and iteration mixed. Take a look at these two:

```
def factor_recursion(n):
    while n>=1:
        return n * factor_recursion(n-1)
    return 1

def factor_iteration_for(n):
    factor = 1
    for i in range(n):
        factor *= i+1
    return factor

def factor_iteration_while(n):
    factor = 1
    while n >= 1:
        factor *= n
        n -= 1
    return factor

print factor_iteration_for(4)
print factor_iteration_while(4)
print factor_recursion(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You never change the value of `n` to anything other than what is passed into the function.

I don't think this is going to do what you think it will. Looks like you've mixed recursion and iteration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, none of your code changes the value of `n`, so the loop will run indefinitely unless `n == 1` when the function is called.

Secondly, you aren't accumulating a partial product inside the loop (hint: before the loop set `result =`, then inside it multiply the current value of `result` by the value of `n`.

Finally, you should then return the accumulated result rather than one.

Answer (score 0):

def factorial(num):

```
    if num == 0:
            return 1
    else:
            return num * factorial(num - 1)
```

print factorial(5)